# Dynamically add column to xts object

Tags: r, xts

Adding a column to an xts object is straightforward if you know the name of the column ahead of time.  For example, to add a column named "b":

```
n <- 5
x <- merge(xts(order.by = as.Date('2015-1-1') + 1:n), a = rnorm(n))
x$b <- rnorm(n)
```

Adding a dynamically-named column (i.e., a column whose name is known only at runtime) is harder:

```
new.col.name <- 'c' # known only at runtime
x[, new.col.name] <- rnorm(n) # this generates an error
```

One approach is to add a column with a temporary name and then rename it:

```
stopifnot(!('tmp' %in% names(x)))
x$tmp <- rnorm(n)
names(x)[names(x) == 'tmp'] <- new.col.name
```

Is there a better way to do this?  (Also, does assigning to `names` of an xts object result in a copy of the object being made?  So, for example, would the above approach work well if `n` were very large?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest/clearest thing to do is merge the original object with the new column(s), after you convert the new column(s) to a matrix (so you can set the column name).

```
set.seed(21)
newData <- rnorm(n)
x1 <- merge(x, matrix(newData, ncol=1, dimnames=list(NULL, new.col.name)))
# another way to do the same thing
dim(newData) <- c(nrow(x), 1)
colnames(newData) <- new.col.name
x2 <- merge(x, newData)
```

To answer your second question: yes, assigning names (and colnames) on an xts object creates a copy. You can see it does by using `tracemem` and the output from `gc`.

```
> R -q  # new R session
R> x <- xts::.xts(1:1e6, 1:1e6)
R> tracemem(x)
[1] "<0x2892400>"
R> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  259260 13.9     592000 31.7   350000 18.7
Vcells 1445207 11.1    4403055 33.6  3445276 26.3
R> colnames(x) <- "hi"
tracemem[0x2892400 -> 0x24c1ad0]: 
tracemem[0x24c1ad0 -> 0x2c62d30]: colnames<- 
tracemem[0x2c62d30 -> 0x3033660]: dimnames<-.xts dimnames<- colnames<- 
tracemem[0x3033660 -> 0x3403f90]: dimnames<-.xts dimnames<- colnames<- 
tracemem[0x3403f90 -> 0x37d48c0]: colnames<- dimnames<-.xts dimnames<- colnames<- 
tracemem[0x37d48c0 -> 0x3033660]: dimnames<-.xts dimnames<- colnames<- 
R> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  259696 13.9     592000 31.7   350000 18.7
Vcells 1445750 11.1    4403055 33.6  3949359 30.2
R> print(object.size(x), units="Mb")
7.6 Mb
```

You can see the `colnames<-` call causes ~4MB of extra memory to be used (the "max used (Mb)" increased by that amount). The entire xts object is ~8MB, half of which is the `coredata` and the other half is the `index`. So the 4MB of extra memory used is to copy the `coredata`.

If you want to avoid the copy, you can set it manually. But be careful, because you could do something that would otherwise be caught by the "checks" in `colnames<-.xts`.

```
> R -q  # new R session
R> x <- xts::.xts(1:1e6, 1:1e6)
R> tracemem(x)
[1] "<0x2cc5330>"
R> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  256397 13.7     592000 31.7   350000 18.7
Vcells 1440915 11.0    4397699 33.6  3441761 26.3
R> attr(x, 'dimnames') <- list(NULL, "hi")
tracemem[0x2cc5330 -> 0x28f4a00]: 
R> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  256403 13.7     592000 31.7   350000 18.7
Vcells 1440916 11.0    4397699 33.6  3441761 26.3
R> print(object.size(x), units="Mb")
7.6 Mb
```

Comment: is merge better than renaming?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no good alternative, but column names are just an attribute, so are cheap to modify, and no copies will be made.
(**EDIT:** uh-oh, just seen I seem to be saying the opposite to Joshua.--> See discussion in comments. It seems `dimnames.xts` does more than just set an attribute, and does involve copying the underlying data, so be careful.)

You can also use `cbind()`, which is a synonym for `merge.xts`, but (AFAIK) it offers no advantage to the `x$b` method you showed:

```
n <- 5
x <- merge(xts(order.by = as.Date('2015-1-1') + 1:n), a = rnorm(n))
x$b <- rnorm(n)
x = cbind(x, c = rnorm(n))
colnames(x)[3] = "real name"
```

I've also showed one way to change the column name. If you don't know it is the 3rd column, then generic approach is: `colnames(x)[length(colnames(x))] = "real name"`

Comment: As I said in my answer, setting `colnames` does create copies. For example: `x <- .xts(1,1); tracemem(x); colnames(x) <- "hi"`

Comment: I was editing, while you added that comment @JoshuaUlrich  The actual matrix data isn't copied is it?

Comment: The actual matrix data is copied, sadly. I've added some detail to my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That sounds crazy! I found `setAttrib()` https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/edc54840351102073c3adf700432d91f2853c389/src/main/attrib.c#L214  but I cannot see anything about copying the underlying data the attributes are attached to.

Comment: Note that I said `colnames<-` creates a copy for xts objects. You're correct that setting attributes does not create a copy, but that's not all `colnames<-` does on an xts object (see `dimnames<-.xts`).

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaUlrich Very educational discussion. I might delete my answer, as I don't think it adds anything now.

Comment: Well, you do show another way to set the column name. Some might find that useful.